# Why does it use simple present of "change" for a past event?

Tags: present-tense, past-simple, present-simple, parallelism

There is dialog on "The Vampire Diaries" that

> "my parents died and everything **changes**"

Why is "changes" used instead of "changed" or "has changed"?

Comment: Please provide more context. Is this a subtitle or are you hearing it?

Comment: it is subtitle.. in supergirl movie i faced that too..

Comment: Matt's that friend since
childhood that you start dating..because you owe it to yourselves
to see if you can be more...And then my parents died,
and everything changes.

Comment: Ok. It makes more sense for it to be "has changed." The subtitle is most likely wrong. I read subtitles in Detective Anna (I don't know Russian), so I know they're not always right.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a mistake in the subtitle, but it's possible that it was a mistake in speech.

In narrative, such as that, we usually use the past *My parents died and everything changed*, but sometimes people use the present, for immediacy: *My parents die, and everything changes*.

But changing from one to the other in the middle of a sentence is a mistake. Genuine spontaneous speech does sometimes do that sort of thing, (the speaker starts, and then forgets how they expressed the first part of the sentence) but I'd be surprised to find it in a script.

Comment: thank you so much..  subtitle wasnt wrong.. i heard that in  speech too